# How to remove space between radiobuttons in pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, grid, radio-button

[image]

How To Remove Padding Between Male And Female RadioButtons?
Here's My Code :

```
def UiComponents(self):
        self.gridbox=QGridLayout()
        self.label=QLabel("What's Your Gender?")
        self.r1=QRadioButton("Male")
        self.r2=QRadioButton("Female")
        self.r3=QRadioButton("Rather Not To Say")
        self.button=QPushButton("Submit")
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label,0,0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.r1,1,0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.r2,1,1)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.r3,1,2)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button,2,0)
        self.setLayout(self.gridbox)
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QGridLayout` works like html table - you got columns and rows, column width is equal to wider widget in column, in your case it's label. To avoid stretching first column, span label across all columns using `columnSpan` argument of `addWidget` (and button too).

```
self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label,0,0,1,3)
...
self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button,2,0,1,3)
```

I would recomend using QtDesigner to create ui, it saves a lot of time and effort and also wysiwyg.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing **spacing** attribute at `setStyleSheet()` method like so

```
r1.setStyleSheet("""
       QRadioButton {
          spacing : 20px; #(<- example value)
       }
""")
```

Comment: No. The `spacing` property of QRadioButton is to specify the distance between the indicator and its text, which is not what the OP is asking.